# Plausible analytics on a server with a webapp

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean, plausible-analytics

I have Django hosted with Nginx on DigitalOcean. Now I want to install Plausible Analytics. How do I do this? How do I change the Nginx config to get to the Plausible dashboard with mydomain/plausible for example?

Answer (score 0):

Setup plausible by either running the software directly or in a docker container - let's say it runs on port 8080

Then in your nginx.conf - you should have a server block for your domain

Within that add a location block with the path you want plausible on and add a proxy pass directive to forward the requests to localhost:8080

Monitor access.log and error.log to debug any issues that may happen